# ¿Cómo cargar 4 Html.DropDownList con muchos datos sin ciclar la vista?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un formulario para registrar a un "Aval", el cuál contiene 4 DropDownList en cascada: Países, Estados, Municipios y Localidades. Todo funciona correctamente al agregar un nuevo aval, pero cuando quiero editar uno ya existente, los DropDownlist se vuelven a vaciar.

Intente solucionarlo desde el controlador así:

```
   public ActionResult Editar(int id = 0)
    {
        if (id!=0)
        {
            ViewBag.paises = ClsAval.GetPaises();
            ViewBag.estados = ClsAval.GetEstados();
            ViewBag.municipios = ClsAval.GetMunicipios();
            ViewBag.localidades = ClsAval.GetLocalidades();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.paises = ClsListas.GetPaises();
            ViewBag.estados = "";
            ViewBag.municipios = "";
            ViewBag.localidades = "";
        }

        ViewBag.Titulo = "Catálogo Aval";
        return View(id == 0 ? new ClsAval() :
        ClsAval.ListarAval(id));
    }
```

El código de la vista:

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label">País:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-8">
                                @Html.DropDownList("IdPais", new SelectList(ViewBag.paises, "IdPais", "NombrePais"), "SELECCIONE UN PAIS", new {Id = "Pais", @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label"> Estado: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-8">
                                @Html.DropDownList("IdEstado", new SelectList(ViewBag.estados, "IdEstado", "NombreEstado"), "SELECCIONE UN ESTADO", new { Id = "Estado", @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label"> Municipio: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-8">
                                @Html.DropDownList("IdMunicipio", new SelectList(ViewBag.municipios, "IdMunicipio", "NombreMunicipio"), "SELECCIONE UN MUNICIPIO", new { Id = "Municipio", @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-4 control-label"> Localidad:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-8">
                                @Html.DropDownList("IdLocalidad", new SelectList(ViewBag.localidades, "IdLocalidad", "NombreLocalidad"), "SELECCIONE UNA LOCALIDAD", new { Id = "Localidad", @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Pero la vista se cicla puesto que son muchos los datos que se cargan en cada DropDownList. Viendo esto, intente seguir la lógica de los DropDownList en cascada de la siguiente forma:

```
public static IEnumerable<ClsListas> GetMunicipios()
    {
        try
        {
            string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            var municipio = new List<ClsListas>();
            var Aval = new ClsAval();
            var conObj = new SqlConnection(connection);
            conObj.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand("Select IdMunicipio, NombreMunicipio from Municipio Where IdEstado =" + Aval.IdEstado, conObj);

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                municipio.Add(new ClsListas { NombreMunicipio = Convert.ToString(reader["NombreMunicipio"]), IdMunicipio = Convert.ToInt32(reader["IdMunicipio"]) });

            }

            return municipio;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex) { throw new Exception(Ex.Message, Ex.InnerException); }
    }
```

Pero no funciono, ya que IdEstado me lo toma como 0. En realidad no estoy muy seguro de que hacer, ¿Hay alguna forma de cargar los 4 sin que se cicle la vista?

Answer (score 1):

Aconsejaria si vas diseñar combos dependientes que lo realices usando ajax en lugar de un post al servidor de esta forma no pierdes los valores en cada ida y vuelta al servidor

Existen varias formas de implementarlo

1-Una opcion podria ser usando jquery, por medio de $.ajax() o $.getJSON() puedes invocar al action del controller que devolvera como respuesta json usado para cargar los items del seguiente combo

[Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cascading-DropDownList-in-833683f9)

[Creating Simple Cascading DropDownList In MVC 4 Using Razor](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/)

la idea es que definas dos dropdownlist pero al primero le adjuntas el evento change de jquery, entonces cuando cambias de opcion lanzara el evento en el cliente, es alli cuando usar el $.ajax para invocar un action en el controller que devolver la lista en json para crear los options del segundo combo

2- Por medio del helper @Html.CascadingDropDownListFor()

[CascadeDropDown Helpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mvc.CascadeDropDown/)

observaras que permite definir en la view como se relaciona con el primer combo

3- Usando @Ajax.BeginForm()

[Simple Implementation of MVC Cascading Ajax Drop Down](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258172/Simple-Implementation-of-MVC-Cascading-Ajax-Drop-D)

Aplicando ajax por medio de un submit al controller creado por el Ajax.BeginForm(), puedes actualizar una seccion de la view para inyectar en esta el html del segundo combo que mostrara los options dependiendo de la seleccion del primer combo

Comment: De hecho lo implemente usando `$.ajax()` con el método `$("#Estado").change` y con un JsonResult, pero los valores se pierden. El CascadeDropDown lo instale pero el proyecto siguió sin reconocerme las referencias

Comment: como que se pierde? si usas el developer tools del browser (al cual accedes con F12) puedes inspeccionar mediante la solapa network la llamada al action y analizar la respuesta, quizas este generandose un error

Comment: La vista para editar y agregar un nuevo registro es la misma. Una vez que le doy al botón de "guardar" me redirecciona a la vista "Index". En Index hay un grid que muestra los registros y desde donde puedes seleccionar uno para editar. Si selecciono un registro me dirige a la vista donde se edita, cada dato sale en un @Html.TextBoxFor excepto por los DropDownList que salen en blanco. Es decir que tengo que volver a elegir un País para elegir un Estado, Municipio y así... Aunque ya anteriormente cuando agregue ese registro por primera vez lo había hecho

Comment: si estas usando jquery despues de cargar el item debes asignar el valor que debe seleccionarse, para esto en el success del $.ajax deberias seleccionar el combo y asignar el valor, pero es algo que debes programar. Recuerda que las llamadas son asincronas por lo tanto deben ir en cascada cuando termina una invocas la carga de la siguiente con la seleccion previa

Comment: El success lo tengo de esta manera:                                                        `success: function (items, responseTexr) {
                $("#Estado").empty();
                $("#Estado").append($("<option/>").val("0").text("SELECCIONE UN ESTADO"));
                $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                    $("#Estado").append($("<option/>").val(item.IdEstado).text(item.NombreEstado));
                });
            },`

Comment: ok pero alli solo estas agregando los options con los datos que llegan desde el controller, pero no veo que asignes usando el $("#Estado").val(valor); el item que deberia seleccionar. Este valor que debes seleccionar lo proporciona la entidad que estas editando

Comment: algo asi? `$("#Municipio").append('<option value="' + item.IdMunicipio + '">' + item.NombreMunicipio + '</option>');`

Comment: con el append() agregas un elemento al combo, debes suar el val() de jquery para seleccionar uno de esos option despues de haber cargados todas las opciones